# How to apply a link to a multiline text string in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a multiline chunk such as this:

```
%li
  =link_to image_tag("image.jpg", :size => "48x48", :alt => "Something", :title => "Something", :class => "some-class"), some_path
  %p.testi
    "Some text right here that is divided up onto multiple lines &amp; 
    %br
    and just won't stop running on!”
```

I need a link to surround both the image and the text.  Presently the image link works fine, however on the text link, I believe I have to start with a link_to block, but I'm not seeing the syntax that I should follow there.

How is this correctly done so that all of the multiple lines of text also have a link applied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In slim (wich should be similar):

```
= link_to some_path, class: "some-class" do
    h2 = "#{some_object.title}"
    p.testi
      "Some text right here that is divided up onto multiple lines &amp; 
    br/
    and just won't stop running on!”
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Multiline string in HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881745/multiline-string-in-haml)

You want to use the | at the end of each line you are wrapping.