# Multiline string in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Because I don't want any of my lines to be wider than 80 columns, I want to split the last line into two lines. Adding a comma at the end of the line works as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930603/haml-syntax-split-a-line-to-a-couple-of-rows?lq=1) but then the comma appears inside the string. Is there a nice and clean way of doing this with HAML?

```
- if object.errors.any?
  %section.form_error_message
    %h4.form_error_message__title
      = "#{pluralize(object.errors.size, 'errors')} prevented this form from submitting. Please fix these errors and try again."
```

I want it all to be tucked inside 80 columns like they are on the left of this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: If these are Texts that you might want to translate later on, you might as well switch to using I18n now. Then you don't have such issues.

Comment: Alternatively, you might save your String in a local variable in the view template using a `:ruby` block.

Comment: Thanks, you're right in that I might as well look at I18n now. I don't think my first rails application will ever finish as I keep coming across another gem to incorporate or another best practice (not that this a bad thing!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Haml has support for multiline sequences](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline) like this using the `|` character:

```
- if object.errors.any?
  %section.form_error_message
    %h4.form_error_message__title
      = "#{pluralize(object.errors.size, 'errors')} prevented this form from |
        submitting. Please fix these errors and try again."                  |
```

In this case you don’t really need this though, you can use [interpolation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_) directly in plain text, you don’t need the `=`:

```
- if object.errors.any?
  %section.form_error_message
    %h4.form_error_message__title
      #{pluralize(object.errors.size, 'errors')} prevented this form from
      submitting. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

(The output of this will be slightly different, as it will include the newline. You should’t notice that in the rendered HTML though, unless you are e.g. inside `<pre>` tags.)

Comment: Sweet! I was unaware that you could interpolate Ruby code inside plain text.

Answer (score 1):

```
%div First line |
     and second line |
```

Will render:

```
<div>First line and second line</div>
```

If you don't even want a tag:

```
First line |
and second line |
```

Will produce:

```
First line and second line
```

You can use the command-tool `haml`, for instance copy the code then `pbpaste | haml` on macOS, or with a file `cat file.haml | haml`.