# Haml how to break up a text-string to meet lint requirements?

Tags: haml

I have a bootstrap alert that is more than 140 characters long. HAML asks that I break up the line using commas, but when I do that the commas end up visible on my webpage. I tried using '|' but apparently the current style-guide doesn't allow it.

How do I break up a %p without using | but still follow the style guide?

Comment: Duplicate question. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882700/16236820)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline string in HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881745/multiline-string-in-haml)